# Convert Encryption from VB6 to .NET

Tags: vb.net, vb6, cryptography, vb6-migration

I used ChilkatCrypt2 for encription in VB6. Now in .NET i want to use System.Security.Cryptography.

I used:

```
Public Function Encripta(pTexto As String, pChave As String, pModo As Byte) As String
    Dim vMD5 As New ChilkatCrypt2
    vMD5.UnlockComponent "..................."
    vMD5.Charset = "utf-8"
    vMD5.KeyLength = 128
    vMD5.CryptAlgorithm = "rijndael"
    vMD5.SecretKey = vMD5.GenerateSecretKey(pChave)
    vMD5.EncodingMode = "hex"
    If pModo = 1 Then
        Encripta = vMD5.EncryptStringENC(pTexto)
    Else
        Encripta = vMD5.DecryptStringENC(pTexto)
    End If
    Set vMD5 = Nothing
End Function
```

Can anyone help me rewrite this in .NET (VB or C#) so that the existing encrypted values decrypt correctly. I can't figure out the parameter equivalence.

Comment: The interoperability will depend on the disclosure & portability of `GenerateSecretKey`, is it documented?

Comment: Hi Alex,                                                       GenerateSecretKey(str As String) As Variant                 Hashes a string to a byte array that has the same number of bits as the current value of the KeyLength property. For example, if KeyLength is equal to 128 bits, then a 16-byte array is returned. This can be used to set the SecretKey property. In order to decrypt, the SecretKey must match exactly. To use "password-based" encryption, the password is passed to this method to generate a binary secret key that can then be assigned to the SecretKey property.

Comment: http://www.chilkatsoft.com/refdoc/xChilkatCrypt2Ref.html

Comment: It looks like the GenerateSecretKey method will prevent you from writing something that can directly decrypt the existing values. You could write an intermediary program that decrypts using the Chilkat component, then re-encrypt the values with your new code. Or you could contact Chilkat and ask if their .NET component will do this.

Comment: Hi jac. I think that's it. No clean solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's like jac said.
Note:The .NET component does it.